# Индексы в MySQL и сортировка

Tags: сортировка, mysql

Привет. Возникло несколько вопросов:

1. Встретил такое понятие как "префиксные индексы(индексы префиксов)".Можно объяснить что имелось ввиду под этим понятием?
2. Что такое файловая сортировка MySQL?
3. Если мы сортируем по каком либо полю, то для оптимизации требуется указать индекс по этому полю (например `INDEX(col)`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Индекс называется префиксным, если самая левая колонка ключа индекса совпа­дает с самой левой колонкой в ключе раздела индекса. Если эти колонки не совпадают, то индекс называется непрефиксным. Суть дела заключается в производительности — непрефиксные индек­сы менее эффективны. Если к разделенной таблице предъявляется за­прос, а в условии отбора фигурирует ключ префиксного индекса, то возможно исключение разделов индекса. Если же индекс непрефиксный, то придется просматривать все разделы индекса. ([отсюда](http://irk-studio.ru/oracle.htm?nid=347))
2. [Using Filesort](http://www.askdev.ru/mysql/4781/%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82-Using-filesort-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-explain-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0/)
3. Подробно описано в [оптимизации ORDER BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) ([русский вариант](http://www.php.su/mysql/manual/?page=ORDER_BY_optimisation)).

Comment: Со вторым и третим вопросом вроде прояснилось ,а вот с 1 ничего не разобрался.Спасибо за материалы.